# fatal: Failed to locate a utility to launch the default web browser in GIT

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg, git-credential-manager

I have a situation with git on WSL

- I use the **Debian distro**.

When trying to push the local to the remote repo: `git push -u origin main`; tries to authenticate but stays in the following:

```
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
fatal: Failed to locate a utility to launch the default web browser.
```

It should be noted that I have globally configured git-credential-manager (NOT git-credential-manager-core)

I have already tried creating the environment variable directly in the shell directory, in my case zsh: `~/.zshrc`; I tried it by setting the `variable = wslview` and also setting the path of the browser in question:

`export BROWSER=wslview`

`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'`

I have also done it by placing the configuration globally;

already used the following:

`git config --global web.browser brave`

`git config --global browser.brave.path '"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"'`

I appreciate who can spare me a few minutes to solve this problem.